# How to hide"Last Modified At" time stamp SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have created a Site Pages library where all my application pages exist. The problem is I am seeing "Last Modified at [Date] by [User]" at the bottom of each page. I do not see this in my other Site Collection that uses the same template. The publishing feature is activated on both as well as versioning.

The class used to display the text I want to hide is ms-descriptiontext. I tried making this display:none but it is a class used throughout SharePoint and hides other pertinent content.

Comment: i think you must use `display:none !important` for your custom css in page.

Comment: I tried this but the class is used throughout Sharepoint on things such as "add column to content type" and other links below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. It turns out when you create a page in the browser through the Site Pages doc lib, the Last Modified time stamp will display at the bottom (regardless of publishing, versioning etc). If you create the page through **SharePoint designer**, as a Web Part Page, there will be no modified time stamp at the bottom!

Answer (score 0):

Calculated Column may work for you. Add a calculated column on the basis of Modified Date that only stores Date (without time stamp). Exclude original Modified Date column from the view, and include calculated column in view.

Visit http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb862071%28v=office.14%29.aspx for calculated column formulas.